# How would I convert this curl command into an AngularJS $http request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, json, curl

I'm currently working on a project with a Rails backend and I need some help with translating this curl command please.  We're using devise to allow a user to sign in but I'm not sure how to implement this into a AngularJS $http request.

curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:3000/users -d

"{\"user\":{\"email\":\"user@example.com\",\"password\":\"password\"}}”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.controller('LoginController', function($http){
    var user = {"user":{"email":"user@example.com","password":"password"}};

    $http.post('http://localhost:3000/users',user).then(function(result){
        // success. do something
    });
});
```

So, you pretty much want to make a post request. For that, inject `$http` service into your `controller` or `service` where you want to make the request and invoke `post` to url with your user data, where user data is a json object.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you read this: http://www.learnwithdaniel.com/2015/10/rails-angular-authentication/